# jquery form plugin

Tags: jquery-forms-plugin

I am trying to use jquery.form.js and for some reason I am unable to call my php script.  At least I can't tell if I am or not.  What does it look like I am doing this incorrectly?

```
    $('#profilepicbutton').live('change', function(){
    $("#preview").html('');
    $("#preview").html('<img src="loader.gif" alt="Uploading...."/>');
        $("registerpt3").ajaxForm({
            target: '#preview'
            }).submit();                
    });
```

The Form...

```
    <form  id="registerpt3" action="register3.php" method="post">
         <input name="profilepicinput" type="file" id="profilepicbutton"  />
         <button type="submit" class="button">Save</button>
    </form>
```

I never seem to call my php function.  Which is corectly labeled above.  How do you call an action using Jquery.Form.js?  Am I doing this incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("registerpt3").ajaxForm({
```

...should be...

```
$("#registerpt3").ajaxForm({
```

Comment: Man, I hate when I do that.  There is no way I should have missed that!  Blasted! 2 hours of banging my head against the wall because of something this stupid!

Comment: @DmainEvent Don't feel bad, it happens to all of us :)